# Numbers after pronouns

Tags: pronouns, numbers, possessive-pronouns

Is saying "**my** three cats" wrong? Should it be "three cats **of mine**"?

My English books says that the latter one is correct, but to my ear, the first one sounds correct too.

Comment: I've never heard of any rule that would indicate "my three cats" was incorrect. Does your book go into any detail at all, any explanation of what's wrong with it?

Comment: I'll try translating the book. "Don't put an article, number nor, for example, pronouns "this/that" or "these/those" in front of pronouns. If you want to use these words, you must choose the double genitive i.e. of-genetive and independent form of the pronoun. Examples: a friend of mine, three cats of his, this letter of hers, those claims of yours"

Comment: I understand that "my a friend, her this letter, your those claim" don't sound right, but the cat one "his three cats" sounds right to me.

Comment: Thank you. It sounds like they're saying not to put the number *before* the pronoun; your example has tne number *after* it.

Comment: Oh right. XD And this is why you should always read carefully

Comment: The three examples you give are certainly wrong; I don't understand why the second word in those cases is needed anywhere -- 'my friend, her letter, your claim" are all all right by themselves.

Comment: **My three cats** implies that you have only three cats. **Three cats of mine** refers only to those particular cats. You may well have several more. Both expressions are fine; they just mean different things.

Comment: @RonaldSole why not post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Putting numbers in front of nouns is accepted, even after determiners. For example, there is a TV program called "[My Three Sons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Three_Sons)". However, there is a difference between **My three cats** and **Three cats of mine** as you were told in the [comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/256419/numbers-after-pronouns#comment481006_256419) by [Ronald Sole](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/41356/ronald-sole):

> My three cats implies that you have only three cats. Three cats of mine refers only to those particular cats. You may well have several more. Both expressions are fine; they just mean different things.